# Access macro: How to get the ID of the current record?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a button that runs a macro that opens another form. Both are connected to the same table. I want the second form to display the same record as the first form.

I don't want to *filter* it to only the same record; I know how to do that. (I use the Where Condition box.) When the new form opens, I want to be able to navigate to the other records.

I tried this:

```
GoToRecord
Record: Go To
Offset: Forms![FirstForm]![ID]
```

That gives an error, probably because the ID number isn't what I'm looking for; it's the *record* number.

So I tried this:

```
GoToRecord
Record: Go To
Offset: Forms![FirstForm].CurrentRecord
```

But that doesn't work either.

I could probably do it in VBA, but I'd feel silly; I'm sure I'm just one keyword away from making this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as noted, if  you use the where clause (and in most cases you should), then of course you get one record, but as noted no navigation to other records.

For some reason I can't get the macro to work.

This VBA snip will work however:

```
  Private Sub Command84_Click()
  
      DoCmd.OpenForm "frmHotelsMain"
  
      Forms("frmHotelsMain").Recordset.FindFirst "ID = " & Me!ID
  
  End Sub
```

However, for some reason, the FindFirst in a macro don't work.

So, two lines of VBA.

I did try a macro with open form, and then a find record - it just does not seem to work.

Comment: That works fine, thanks; I've marked it as Accepted. I still hope someone will come up with a Macro answer.

Comment: I almost thinking that this is a bug - i simply don't know why a open form, and findrecord in a macro does not work - I simply don't know why a macro does not work.